# Trigger popup on href - Please log in message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If a user is not logged in on my site I would like to trigger a popup to load without sending the user off to another page. I have been trying to do this with this code, but I cant get it to work for some reason. Where is my mistake? Thanks a million.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/gyeo03nk/1/

```js
// POPUP WINDOW CODE

$(document).ready(function () {

 // if user clicked on button, the overlay layer or the dialogbox, close the dialog 
 $('a.btn-ok, #dialog-overlay, #dialog-box').click(function () {  
  $('#dialog-overlay, #dialog-box').hide();  
  return false;
 });
 
 // if user resize the window, call the same function again
 // to make sure the overlay fills the screen and dialogbox aligned to center 
 $(window).resize(function () {
  
  //only do it if the dialog box is not hidden
  if (!$('#dialog-box').is(':hidden')) popup();  
 }); 
 
 
});

//Popup dialog
function popup(message) {
  
 // get the screen height and width  
 var maskHeight = $(document).height();  
 var maskWidth = $(window).width();
 
 // calculate the values for center alignment
 var dialogTop =  (maskHeight/3) - ($('#dialog-box').height());  
 var dialogLeft = (maskWidth/2) - ($('#dialog-box').width()/2); 
 
 // assign values to the overlay and dialog box
 $('#dialog-overlay').css({height:maskHeight, width:maskWidth}).show();
 $('#dialog-box').css({top:dialogTop, left:dialogLeft}).show();
 
 // display the message
 $('#dialog-message').html(message);
   
}
```

```css
/* Popup window ----------------------------------------*/

#dialog-overlay {

 /* set it to fill the whil screen */
 width:100%; 
 height:100%;
 
 /* transparency for different browsers */
 filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
 -moz-opacity:0.5; 
 -khtml-opacity: 0.5; 
 opacity: 0.5; 
 background:#000; 

 /* make sure it appear behind the dialog box but above everything else */
 position:absolute; 
 top:0; left:0; 
 z-index:3000; 

 /* hide it by default */
 display:none;
}


#dialog-box {
 
 /* css3 drop shadow */
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 
 /* css3 border radius */
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 
 background:#eee;
 /* styling of the dialog box, i have a fixed dimension for this demo */ 
 width:328px; 
 
 /* make sure it has the highest z-index */
 position:absolute; 
 z-index:5000; 

 /* hide it by default */
 display:none;
}

#dialog-box .dialog-content {
 /* style the content */
 text-align:left; 
 padding:10px; 
 margin:13px;
 color:#666; 

}


/* extra styling */
#dialog-box .dialog-content p {
 font-weight:700; margin:0;
}

#dialog-box .dialog-content ul {
 margin:10px 0 10px 20px; 
 padding:0; 
 height:50px;
}/* Popup window ----------------------------------------*/

#dialog-overlay {

 /* set it to fill the whil screen */
 width:100%; 
 height:100%;
 
 /* transparency for different browsers */
 filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
 -moz-opacity:0.5; 
 -khtml-opacity: 0.5; 
 opacity: 0.5; 
 background:#000; 

 /* make sure it appear behind the dialog box but above everything else */
 position:absolute; 
 top:0; left:0; 
 z-index:3000; 

 /* hide it by default */
 display:none;
}


#dialog-box {
 
 /* css3 drop shadow */
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 
 /* css3 border radius */
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 
 background:#eee;
 /* styling of the dialog box, i have a fixed dimension for this demo */ 
 width:328px; 
 
 /* make sure it has the highest z-index */
 position:absolute; 
 z-index:5000; 

 /* hide it by default */
 display:none;
}

#dialog-box .dialog-content {
 /* style the content */
 text-align:left; 
 padding:10px; 
 margin:13px;
 color:#666; 

}


/* extra styling */
#dialog-box .dialog-content p {
 font-weight:700; margin:0;
}

#dialog-box .dialog-content ul {
 margin:10px 0 10px 20px; 
 padding:0; 
 height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialog-overlay"></div>
<div id="dialog-box">
 <div class="dialog-content">
  <div id="dialog-message"></div>
  <a href="#" class="button-small">close</a>
 </div>
</div>
    
 <a href="#" onclick="return popup('Please Log in');">A click here should launch the popup? Hmm</a>
```

Comment: if you check for console errors, you have a `Uncaught ReferenceError: popup is not defined` error right ?

Comment: The `popup()` function call is missing a parameter

Comment: Have a look at this: [http://jsfiddle.net/gyeo03nk/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/gyeo03nk/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

Instead of calling `popup` through HTML, I've called it through jQuery.

```js
// POPUP WINDOW CODE

$(document).ready(function () {

 // if user clicked on button, the overlay layer or the dialogbox, close the dialog 
 $('a.btn-ok, #dialog-overlay, #dialog-box').click(function () {  
  $('#dialog-overlay, #dialog-box').hide();  
  return false;
 });
 
 // if user resize the window, call the same function again
 // to make sure the overlay fills the screen and dialogbox aligned to center 
 $(window).resize(function () {
  
  //only do it if the dialog box is not hidden
  if (!$('#dialog-box').is(':hidden')) popup("Hello");  
 }); 
 
    //This is the modified code
    $('.login').click(function(){
        popup('Please log in');
    });
 
});

//Popup dialog
function popup(message) {
  
 // get the screen height and width  
 var maskHeight = $(document).height();  
 var maskWidth = $(window).width();
 
 // calculate the values for center alignment
 var dialogTop =  (maskHeight/3) - ($('#dialog-box').height());  
 var dialogLeft = (maskWidth/2) - ($('#dialog-box').width()/2); 
 
 // assign values to the overlay and dialog box
 $('#dialog-overlay').css({height:maskHeight, width:maskWidth}).show();
 $('#dialog-box').css({top:dialogTop, left:dialogLeft}).show();
 
 // display the message
 $('#dialog-message').html(message);
   
}
```

```css
/* Popup window ----------------------------------------*/

#dialog-overlay {

 /* set it to fill the whil screen */
 width:100%; 
 height:100%;
 
 /* transparency for different browsers */
 filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
 -moz-opacity:0.5; 
 -khtml-opacity: 0.5; 
 opacity: 0.5; 
 background:#000; 

 /* make sure it appear behind the dialog box but above everything else */
 position:absolute; 
 top:0; left:0; 
 z-index:3000; 

 /* hide it by default */
 display:none;
}


#dialog-box {
 
 /* css3 drop shadow */
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 
 /* css3 border radius */
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 
 background:#eee;
 /* styling of the dialog box, i have a fixed dimension for this demo */ 
 width:328px; 
 
 /* make sure it has the highest z-index */
 position:absolute; 
 z-index:5000; 

 /* hide it by default */
 display:none;
}

#dialog-box .dialog-content {
 /* style the content */
 text-align:left; 
 padding:10px; 
 margin:13px;
 color:#666; 

}


/* extra styling */
#dialog-box .dialog-content p {
 font-weight:700; margin:0;
}

#dialog-box .dialog-content ul {
 margin:10px 0 10px 20px; 
 padding:0; 
 height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog-overlay"></div>
<div id="dialog-box">
 <div class="dialog-content">
  <div id="dialog-message"></div>
  <a href="#" class="button-small">close</a>
 </div>
</div>
    
 <a href="#" class="login">A click here should launch the popup? Hmm</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not adding your javascript in  tag.
Add your JS code in head tag instead of adding it in body.
Look at this fiddle. Its working fine.

```
fiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gyeo03nk/4

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the in-line onclick and put an on click event on your link.

```
<a href="#" id="popupButton">A click here should launch the popup? Hmm</a>
```

Then in your javascript file...

```
$('#popupButton').on('click', function(){
    var message = 'Please Log in';
    popup(message);
});
```